# Google Maps Embedding without Arrow Marker

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-embed

I'm trying to embed a Google Map solely using longitude and latitude coordinates (supplied from a MySQL database). So far, I've been pretty successful, but I have one last hurdle I'm struggling with. Here's my embed code:

```
<iframe width="250" height="193" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=<?=$result_array['lat']?>,<?=$result_array['long']?>&amp;aq=&amp;sll=<?=$result_array['lat']?>,<?=$result_array['long']?>&amp;sspn=0.000647,0.001246&amp;t=m&amp;gl=us&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;ll=<?=$result_array['lat']?>,<?=$result_array['long']?>&amp;spn=0.011505,0.018239&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

I've gotten to a point where using only one set of coordinates, I can pinpoint the right place on the map, but the place is marked with an arrow and the relevant landmark. Does anyone know of a way to get rid of the green arrow?

Here's what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/9fmwM/6/

Comment: This may help you, possibly a duplicate question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2344137/embedding-google-maps-how-to-eliminate-unwanted-marker

Comment: Seems like the same question, but the answer doesn't cover embedded maps.I'd like to avoid using the static maps API if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the saddr-parameter instead of the q-parameter:

```
<iframe style="min-height: 99%; width: 100%;" 
        frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
        marginheight="0" 
        marginwidth="0" 
        src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;saddr=37.42216,-122.083737&amp;source=s_d&amp;hl=en&amp;z=15&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/kUsCP/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/kUsCP/)

Comment: Since saddr is used for driving directions, it seems to pick a point on the road nearest to the coordinates specified. Although it does only display the marker and not the arrow, unfortunately I need a little bit more accuracy than this. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Comment: Not working anymore.

Answer (score -1):

[Click here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start) to create a embed google maps without marker and select the option *Just show a map of an area!*